Help identifying gambling? movie
I don't remember a lot of the details from the film at all, but one scene stands out rather vividly.
The main character is a young man, in his 20s/30s, visiting his dying father at the hospital. He is approached by another man who is a family member of some sort, with whom he gets into a disagreement. The only "quote" I remember is the protagonist's last remark, when he says something along the lines of:
"We are not family. Any family connection you and I share dies along with my father."

How old is this movie?

That last line sounds very familiar

Possibly 'Family Business' (1989), with Broderick, Hoffman and Connery. But it's years since I saw it and I can't remember details - reading your question this film came straight to mind

It sounds like the movie 13
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0798817/
The father is in hospital, and his family is struggling financially.  One day the son hears about a secret gambling ring in which a bunch of guys play Russian roulette.  The guy who was supposed to be in it dies of a drug overdose, and the son goes in this guys place. 
However I can't remember that exact quote in the movie.  The only movie that I can remember that has a quote very similar to this is The Departed. 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1
Billy says "When my mother dies, we don't have any more connection." to his uncle.  However this was a woman dying, not a man.  And it really isn't a gambling movie.

I have a strong hunch that this movie is "The Departed". Leonardo DiCaprio plays the lead role as Billy Costigan, an undercover police officer. Billy was speaking to his mother's brother, outside her hospital room telling him that when she passed away, there'll no longer be a connection to family.
I hope this helps with identifying the movie.

This movie is already mentioned in another answer. There is no need to duplicate answers.
